# What is relation between type and format of texture

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am working on volumetric rendering raw data in three.js. I have a hard time understanding the relationship between the type and format of the texture (in my case it is texture3d) in three.js.

Available type of texture type are : 
[image]

and available format are: 
[image]

I tried to put type as THREE.UnsignedIntType for **u8int** datatype of raw data but it gives invalid internalformat of texture error but everything works fine with type of *THREE.UnsignedByteType*.

this is my code of texture,

```
    var texture = new THREE.DataTexture3D(data, dims[0], dims[1], dims[2]);
    texture.format = THREE.RedFormat;
    texture.type = THREE.UnsignedByteType;
```

Could anyone please say how both are related. I cannot make static since the raw data type can be of any bit (8/16/32) and type(int/float).

Comment: Where did you put `THREE.UnsignedIntType` into?

Comment: @BDL I put that in texture, I have edited my question where I have added code. dims is an array of length of raw data in three directions. I put UnSignedIntType in the third line of the code above error comes with invalid internalformat.As per three.js documentation, library itself takes internalformat attribute from type and format of the texture.It can also be assigned manually though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three.js texture format and types are aliases for the WebGL formats and types. Only certain combinations are allowed.

The list of valid combinations for WebGL1 is

```
| format          | type
+-----------------+------
| RGBA            | UNSIGNED_BYTE
| RGB             | UNSIGNED_BYTE
| RGBA            | UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4
| RGBA            | UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1
| RGB             | UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5
| LUMINANCE_ALPHA | UNSIGNED_BYTE
| LUMINANCE       | UNSIGNED_BYTE
| ALPHA           | UNSIGNED_BYTE
```

So translating that to three.js is

```
| format               | type
+----------------------+------
| RGBAFormat           | UnsignedByteType
| RGBFormat            | UnsignedByteType
| RGBAFormat           | UnsignedShort4444
| RGBAFormat           | UnsignedShort5551
| RGBFormat            | UnsignedShort565
| LuminanceAlphaFormat | UnsignedByteType
| LuminanceFormat      | UnsignedByteType
| AlphaFormat          | UnsignedByteType
```

Note: WebGL1 does not support 3D textures directly although you can implement them yourself via creative shaders

[WebGL2 allows a much larger list of combinations](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-data-textures.html)

Note that the format/type combination is the format and type of the data you are supplying to three.js, **not** the format of the texture that data will be stored in.

To specify the internal format you set `texture.internalFormat`. To specify `format` and `type` you can set `texture.format` and `texture.type`

Only certain combinations of format/type can be used as input for a given internal format. See the link above for the list.

If you want 1 channel unsigned int texture you need to set

```
texture.internalFormat = 'R32UI';
texture.format = THREE.RedIntegerFormat;
texture.type = THREE.UnsignedIntType;
```

You'll also need to make sure you set `texture.minFilter` and `texture.magFilter` to `THREE.NearestFilter` and you'll need to make sure your shaders use `uniform usampler3D someSamplerName;`

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const context = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, context});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const data = new Uint32Array([1234]);
  const texture = new THREE.DataTexture3D(data, 1, 1, 1);
  texture.internalFormat = 'R32UI';
  texture.format = THREE.RedIntegerFormat;
  texture.type = THREE.UnsignedIntType;

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const shader = {
    uniforms: {
      threeD: { value: texture },
    },
    vertexShader: `#version 300 es
      void main() {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
      }
    `,
    fragmentShader: `#version 300 es
      #include <common>

      uniform highp usampler3D threeD;
      out vec4 c;
      
      void main() {
        uvec4 color = texture(threeD, vec3(0));
        // this also works
        // uvec4 color = texelFetch(threeD, ivec3(0), 0);
        c = vec4(float(color.r) / 2468.0, 0, 0, 1);
      }
    `,
  };


  const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shader);

  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
</script>
```

With RGIntegerFormat and UnsignedByteType you need to use internal format `RG8UI` and pass your data in as `Uint8Array`

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const context = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, context});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// THREE.RGIntegerFormat as format and THREE.UnsignedByteType

  const data = new Uint8Array([11, 22]);
  const texture = new THREE.DataTexture3D(data, 1, 1, 1);
  texture.internalFormat = 'RG8UI';
  texture.format = THREE.RGIntegerFormat;
  texture.type = THREE.UnsignedByteType;
window.t = THREE;
  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const shader = {
    uniforms: {
      threeD: { value: texture },
    },
    vertexShader: `#version 300 es
      void main() {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
      }
    `,
    fragmentShader: `#version 300 es
      #include <common>

      uniform highp usampler3D threeD;
      out vec4 c;
      
      void main() {
        uvec4 color = texture(threeD, vec3(0));
        // this also works
        // uvec4 color = texelFetch(threeD, ivec3(0), 0);
        c = vec4(vec2(color.rg) / vec2(22), 0, 1);
      }
    `,
  };


  const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shader);

  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @gman, but I still have the difficulty, when I put  THREE.RGIntegerFormat as format and THREE.UnsignedByteType,  this combination is in the table of webgl2 with Source Bytes Per Pixel as 2. The input data is uint16 BUT this gives error of invalid internal format.

Comment: The type of source always matches the type. So if you type is UnsignedByteType then you use Uint8Array. Further RGIntegerFormat only works with RG integer internal formats like RG8I, RG8UI, RG16I, RG16UI, RG32I, RG32UI.

Comment: On the page u mentioned, there is a table for the list of internalformat, type, format, and source byte per pixel. Source byte per pixel is related with input data right? When i have 16 bit data, i should look for value 2  in source byte per pixel ? Input data type is uint16 so i went to type as UnsignedByteType for even with 16 bit data. Could you suggest me for Uint16 data. I want to build a function which return the type and format or internaltype if needed according to data type( datatype is available in variable like uint16).

Comment: srcData = Uint16Array, internalformat = RG16UI, format = RGIntegerFormat, type = UnsignedShortType. There are then two 16 bit values per pixel.

Comment: For uint16 this values gives an error of  arraybufferview not big enough for request though I have set unpackalignemnt =1 . unit16 works fine with type=UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 and format = RGBA ?

Comment: I have one ambiguity. To apply alpha blending does it need the texture should have an alpha component in it? I enabled the alpha component with material.blending = THREE.CustomBlending but it has no effect on output.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't realise I had to set the internalFormat of the texture.